# How to keep all data when switching from dual-boot system to single OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows

I run Ubuntu on a few older computers of mine. I'm planning on setting up a dual-boot system on my main laptop, which currently runs Windows 10.

I know how to process works and everything, but I have one question:

I'm choosing to dual-boot for now just in case I come across something that's required for my school that isn't available on Linux. Hopefully, I'll eventually switch to Ubuntu completely. If I do eventually completely switch to Ubuntu only, what's the easiest way to keep all my data while doing that transition? I'd just use a USB, but is there a more seamless way?

When installing new OSs on other PCs, I've never had to worry about keeping any data on the disk, but this will have all my school stuff on it.

Edit: I'm going to use 20.04

Comment: The best/safest way is to always backup your data in an external medium and/or the cloud.

Comment: Changing Operating Systems and Re-partitioning are *inherently risky*. If you value it, back it up. There are clever ways to do what you seek to accomplish, but do you really have a couple free days to devote to data recovery if something goes wrong?